# Как защититься от ботов без капчи?

Tags: php, безопасность, веб-программирование

На сайте (PHP) есть регистрация, в ней не используется капча и, согласно ТЗ, внедрить ее нельзя. В форме регистрации используются уникальные поля, при отправке формы происходит проверка на частоту запросов с ip адреса источника. Но что, если ботнет в несколько тысяч машин будет слать запросы на регистрацию? Как это предотвратить?

Comment: Как вариант фильтровать содержимое. Ботнет стоит денег, информация с него как правило, содержит рекламную информацию, ссылки или телефоны. Можно фильтровать размещаемое содержимое по ссылкам, телефонам, в более сложном случае можно попробовать прикрутить и обучить байесовскую сеть.

Comment: если конкретно какой бот, узнав в логах веб-сервера, то в htaсcess его прибить окончательно!

Comment: @Andrey А бывают ситуации когда зловредный бот говорит как его зовут? Прямо вот так: "Здравствуйте! Я бот Вася, я буду сейчас делать на вас распределенную атаку, но вы можете написать в .htaccess `Require expr "!(%{USER-AGENT} =~ /Вася/)"` и у вас все будет хорошо"

Comment: @tutankhamun, большая половина ботов это где-то около 90% себя идентифицирую, это на моей практике. Или в их запросах есть "ТО" по чем их можно прибивать. Другое дело что их не мало.

Comment: @Andrey Половины обычно равны :) Мне кажется вы путаете ботов, которые несут вред и служебных ботов. Боты, например, поисковиков совершенно не прячутся, а вот если попадете под атаку, там будует целый зоопарк валидных UA от браузеров (IE, Webkit, Gecko и тому подобное)

Comment: @tutankhamun Я думаю, конечно, бывают, но заранее их не предусмотришь? По крайней мере если еще не был подвержен такой атаке

Comment: @АндрейТаланин насколько видел, обычно они себя идентифицируют нормальным юзер-агентом хрома или мозилы)) Тут же речь идёт о ботах которые регистрацию проходят, а не просто контент парсят

Answer (score 6):

Если переформулировать заголовок на более осмысленный, то ответ становится очевиден:

> Как защититься от ботов без капчи?

**Нельзя.**

В общем случае капча - это единственный способ отличить бота от человека. Нет капчи - нет защиты. Просто как 2х2.

В конкретных же случаях ответ будет не столь однозначный, но весьма неприятный -

**думать**

Этот способ помогает при решении любых сложных вопросов.
К сожалению, никаких готовых рецептов не существует, и полагать что достаточно написать вопрос в интернете как разу набегут специалисты и решат за тебя проблему, достаточно наивно.

Применять можно лишь какие-то частные решения, но при этом не ту ерунду которую советуют в других ответах, типа HTTP заголовков или JS (самый ад - это слежка за пользователем на клиенте. Впрочем, если задача вместе с ботами отсеять и честных посетителей, то способ вполне годится), а сначала смоделировать предполагаемое поведение как честного юзера, так и атакующего злоумышленника. 
И строить защиту на основе этих теоретических моделей, корректируя их по результатам практического использования.

Comment: Ну да, советы давали наобум - вдруг поможет? Ни разу не находились по обе стороны баррикад, ни разу не думали что поможет.

Comment: Ваш ответ, кстати довольно-таки грамотный, и я поставил ему плюс

Comment: Я благодарен. Но всё же Вы резковаты и слишком категоричны.

Comment: Да будешь тут резким, когда аудитории ближе всего простые и доступные, но бессмысленные камлания, которые и ботов не остановят, и такой вал фальшивых срабатываний дадут, что пользователи разбегутся еще быстрее, чем от капчи

Comment: Резкость это не исправит. Вы ведь тоже ответа по темен не дали. В любом случае вопрос слишком общий, чтобы можно было дать конкретный и законченный ответ.

Comment: Если на то пошло, то можно переформулировать вопрос еще более осмысленно "Как защититься от ботов?" с тем же ответом. Бот это ведь не всегда только скрипт

Comment: @tutankhamun, та же проблема - на этот вопрос нельзя достаточно лаконично ответить, это целый раздел информационной безопасности.

Answer (score 5):

Не реклама (хотя может и да, но мне никто не платил за неё).

[Distil Networks](http://www.distilnetworks.com/) - то, что нужно.
Я как-то пытался пробиться на защищённый ими сайт, поэтому на своём опыте могу сказать что это работает.
Но если кто-то поставит себе задачу пробиться именно на Ваш сайт - ничто не спасёт:
Дистил я обошёл (с трудом), капчу тоже ([рукапча](https://rucaptcha.com), например), скрытые поля не скроются, если снифать запросы (тут же фиксятся проблемы "нечеловеческих" заголовков); проверки JS обходятся тем же [фантомом](http://phantomjs.org/); проверка действий пользователя так же отслеживается и воспроизводится.

Хорошая новость в том, что если нет цели атаковать именно Ваш ресурс, Distil Networks вполне поможет: проверка IP, JS, поведенческий фактор, что там ещё. Вишенкой является то, что боты будут атаковать их сервера, т. к. делегируется в DNS.
А если платить неохота, придётся самим проверять все факторы выше.

Answer (score 4):

От направленной атаки спасет только сервис защиты от DDoS. От множественной регистрации поможет (но не на 100% спасет) следующее:

1. Проверка валидности заголовков, формируемых баузером, например `User-Agent`. Крайне слабая защита, но от некоторых ботов защитит;
2. Внедрение скрытых проверочных полей, которые не должны быть заполнены. Чем больше вариантов скрытия вы придумаете, тем лучше;
3. Заполнение некоторых полей через JS. Многие боты пока этого не умеют, да и наличие JS это дополнительные ресурсы;
4. Наблюдение за поведением пользователя через JS. Далеко не все боты имеют JS и умеют имитировать действия поьзователя (движение мышью, прокрутка, нажатия на клавиши и т. д.);
5. Ну и старая добрая постмодерация с возможностью ее включения на диапазоны IP и по условиям проверки HTTP-заголовков.