# Бота curl действительно так легко определить?

Tags: php, curl

Допустим человек написал на твой сайт php curl бота где он авторизовуется и что то делает, у меня есть подозрение, и я просто добавляю новую строку post данных, например при нажатии на любую кнопку, те кто в браузере ничего не изменится, а вот бот мне не пришлет этот параметр, так как его создатель еще об этом не знает, и я его забаню. Все ли верно?
Да я понимаю что он новый напишет все такое, но в контексте что я написал все будет так?

Comment: Не понятна ваша идея проверки бота. Какая строка пост-данных... Что то я потерял нить человек пришлет бот нет. Человек то не шлет, шлет браузер.

Comment: Похожий вопрос вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564443/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%87%d0%b8/564461

Comment: Если в общем, то сейчас методы защиты такие (от простых к сложным) 1. Проверка просто, поддерживается ли javascript (простейшие боты не умееют javascript в полном обьеме выполнять). 2. Капча. 3. Прослеживание активности мыши и клавиатуры. Бот не будет елозить по тач-скрину или делать последовательные движения мышкой. Не будет ждать 3-4 сек, а сразу заполнит все поля и нажмет на кнопку submit и т п.  Есть и другие методы... А ещё можно так http://images11.popmeh.ru/upload/img_cache/7ff/7ff74f587325afc4105eb6207d0ca0aa_ce_1068x708x0x0_cropped_800x427.png

Comment: Обычно, для сайта если пишется бот (поисковые легко фильтруются), то пишется не просто так, а что б получить доступ либо к информации, либо к какой-то услуге. Бот как правило затачивается на конкретные действия, такие же, какие надо делать в браузере. Если бот "собьется", то писаки бота подправят его так, что б он по прежнему нажимал нужную кнопку с нужным текстом (содержанием).